# How to set part of a path dynamically for alias command in bashrc file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to have a alias command and the part of its path keeps changing. 
Eg:

```
/var/mywork/swag/wsnew/
/var/mywork/swag/ws/
/var/mywork/swag/wsold/
```

and my alias command to achieve is something link this

alias cws='cd /var/mywork/swag//

since last directory in the path is keep changing. I wanted to get automatically update in alias command. Is there anyway ?

I tried something like

alias cws='cd /var/mywork/swag/getenv("WSP")/

so whenever I set WSP to required path it automatically takes. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Like most problems with aliases, this is easier to solve with a shell function:

```
cws() {
    cd /var/mywork/swag/"$WSP"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like melpomene said, you are better off using a function, but if you, for whatever reason, want to stick with an alias, you can do

```
alias cws='cd /var/mywork/swag/$WSP'
```

But note that this differs from using a shell function in one point, which is related to setting a variable for just one command: If you write

```
WSP=aaa
...
WSP=xxx
...
WSP=yyy cws
```

and `cws` is defined as a function, this would cd to yyy, but if it is an alias, it would cd to xxx.

Comment: Yep. Same result with slightly different syntax, just in the possibility that variety makes it a little easier to grasp what's going on: `alias cws="cd /var/mywork/swag/\$WSP"` Quoting the `$` makes it evaluate at execution time rather than once only when set, but wouldn't it be easier to have a function that could take an argument? Listen to the Muse. :)

Comment: Sure, a function with an argument such as `${1:-${WSP:-some_nice_default}}` would be more flexible, and this is what I would do in this case; if I understand the OP correctly, he doesn't intend to change `WSP` often, so his function would usually be invoked without arguments. Another option to consider would be to set `CDPATH=.:/var/mywork/swag` and get rid of alias and function.